# sha256sum elementaryos-5.1-stable.20200204.iso correct?

Tags: system-installation, download

I downloaded the image just for a testing purpose and was wondering, if the mentioned sha256sum cd66c32d53eab6f789b8e69e499305b7af0c9b3083ed54d50b111136d2795ea1 on your installation page is correct?
I downloaded the image twice and got both times the same sha256sum 190bbf738db0f15daa9ee4095bb64c307950082819081a969f8edd51f1faab07.
Now I am a little bit in doubt if I can test elementary OS with my same copy or if I got a tampered and therfore untrusted ISO file
Can you please have a check if the sha256sum on your documentation page is right?